# What is the difference between an indicator function and indicator random variable?

Tags: probability, functions

Are they the same? My probability class uses the term indicator random variable, but it seems like indicator function is also used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're the same thing. The reason for this is that formally, random variables are just functions. They map every single outcome in the sample space $\Omega$ to a real number.

For example, If $\Omega = \{ (1,1), (1,2), \cdots, (6,5), (6,6) \}$ is the set of the 36 different outcomes when rolling two distinguishable dice, then we can define a random variable $X : \Omega \to \Bbb R$ which maps each outcome to the sum of the two numbers rolled: $X( (n_1,n_2) ) := n_1 + n_2$. E.g. $X( (3,4) ) = 7$.

An indicator random variable is a special kind of random variable, where the range of the function that corresponds to the random variable is $\{ 0, 1 \}$ instead of $\Bbb R$. So an indicator random variable is the same thing as an indicator function, and vice versa.

In this case, we could define $A \subseteq X$ such that $A = \{ (1,6), (2,5), (3,4), (4,3), (5,2), (6,1) \}$ (i.e. all outcomes where the numbers rolled sum to $7$). Then the indicator random variable $1_A$ is just a function $1_A: \Omega \to \{ 0,1 \}$ such that $1_A(a) = 1$ if $a \in A$ and $1_A(a) = 0$ if $a \notin A$. You could also call $1_A$ an indicator function. It doesn't really matter. An interesting property of indicator random variables / indicator functions is that $P(A) = E[1_A]$. So $P(A) = \frac{|A|}{|\Omega|} = \frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $A\subseteq \Omega$ and not $A\subseteq X$?

Answer (score 1):

A *random variable* is a function that maps outcomes of a sample space to real values.

An *indicator function* has a codomain of binary values, $\{0,1\}$.   It is a piecewise function typically used to indicate whether an argument is within a given interval.   That is to say that for some set $\mathcal A$ with subset $\mathcal I$, then the indicator function $\mathbf 1_{\mathcal I}$ is defined such that for all $x\in \mathcal A$ then : $$\mathbf 1_\mathcal I(x) =\begin{cases}1 &:& x\in \mathcal I\\ 0 &:& x\notin \mathcal I\end{cases}$$

(Sometimes also written as $\mathbf 1_{x\in\mathcal I}$ )

When the domain happens to be the sample space (and thus interval is an event) then such an indicator function is called an *indicator random variable*.   Usually written in the form of $\mathbf 1_E$, it is the indicator that the realised outcome is within event $E$ ; that is, it has the value of $1$ if the event occurs, otherwise $0$.